# Is there a better way to write this Jade when using Knockout?

Tags: knockout.js, pug

I love Jade for its terse syntax but when doing some basic Knockout binding, it's getting ugly:

```
section
  h2.page-title(data-bind='text: title')
  div(data-bind='foreach: customers')
    .well
      address
        | ID: // there is a space at the end of this line
        span(data-bind='text: id')
        div(data-bind='text: name')
        div(data-bind='text: address.street')
        span(data-bind='text: address.city')
        | , // there is a space at the end of this line
        span(data-bind='text: address.state')
        |   // there is a space at the end of this line
        span(data-bind='text: address.zip')
```

A few things are just plain awkward about this. First of all, the need for all of the `div` and `span` tags to hang `data-bind` off of seems to force a lot of multi-line representations of what are rendered as single lines. That's a common issue with Jade made worse by combination with Knockout.

Additionally, I have three cases of something that I often run into when I'm have to split lines like this: spaces at the end of lines needed to space inline elements (marked by comments in the code). Unless I pepper by code with comments like this, they look no different in an editor from lines without spaces. It's easy to accidentally delete them or simply not be able to tell if you remembered to put one where it should be.

Here it is in HTML:

```
<section>
  <h2 data-bind="text: title" class="page-title"></h2>
  <div data-bind="foreach: customers">
    <div class="well">
      <address>
        ID: <span data-bind="text: id"></span>
        <div data-bind="text: name"></div>
        <div data-bind="text: address.street"></div>
        <span data-bind="text: address.city"></span>, <span data-bind="text: address.state"></span>
        <span data-bind="text: address.zip"></span>
      </address>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

While more annoying to type out, it's much more readable as HTML. I'm this close to giving up on Jade (at least in a Knockout-heavy context) but I'm hoping someone with better Jade-fu can improve the readability of this seemingly common use-case. And I'm hoping it can be improved with pure Jade alterations since modifying my data to contain a pre-formatted id or city/state/zip string etc. is not an option.

Comment: That's the usual "haml sucks for markup" :p

Comment: I'm afraid you're right.

Comment: I actually use `= "stuff with space at the end "` instead of `|`

Comment: Keep in mind you can use `#[span text]` for inline elements, i.e.,
`div #[span(data-bind="text: address.city") New York], #[span(data-bind="text: address.state") NY]`

Answer (score 1):

It's still far from elegant, but using &nbsp is more transparent than just leaving the trailing spaces, and gets rid of the need for the ridiculous comments:

```
section
  h2.page-title(data-bind='text: title')
  div(data-bind='foreach: customers')
    .well
      address
        | ID: &nbsp;
        span(data-bind='text: id')
        div(data-bind='text: name')
        div(data-bind='text: address.street')
        span(data-bind='text: address.city')
        | , &nbsp;
        span(data-bind='text: address.state')
        | &nbsp;
        span(data-bind='text: address.zip')
```